# MVC - Passing item.Id in View to variable for modal form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hard to explain in my title but essentially what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a view which displays some client Info in a table:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(x => x.User == User.Identity.GetUserName()))
    {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Client_ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Clients", new { id = item.Id })"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Client_Name)</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact_Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact_Mobile)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sendFormModal" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Form" onclick="@ " />           
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

From here, each Item generates a row and within each row I have a button. I am looking to link the item.Id and other info with that button, so when I click the button it opens a modal and I can use the ID to get other data from my table.

The modal requires some input from the user, before another button sends an email. Hence, I require to get some other info from my table (email address included). I have the rest of the process working, but just cannot figure out how to pass any of the data from that row to the modal/button on the same row.

Modal Code FYI

```
        <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="sendFormModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Send Client Data</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Select a Form</p>
                    <select class="form-control" id="formSelection">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>Test</option>
                    </select><br />
                    <p>Input your custom message</p>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="formMessage"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" onclick="SendClientForm()" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Send</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check this post, as i did same what you need to : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1191769/Grid-View-with-AJAX-based-CRUD-Operations-in-ASP-N

Comment: Rather than getting the email from the first view's table, I would use the id that is passed to the controller (when the first view's button is clicked) to get all of the info you need for the modal.